# Why is if statement not working?

Tags: bash

I'm not sure why my if statement is not working. It prompts to enter Weekly Salary even if $EmployeeType is Commission or Hourly. Should I be using if statement for all instead of elif? I tried using all if statements but keep having error "syntax error near unexpected token "}"". 
Please kindly advice.

Output:

```
Enter Payroll of an employee 

Enter employee name: Mary
Mary is Hourly employee.

Enter Weekly Salary :




payroll_employee()
{

   echo
   echo "[Option: $input]"
   echo "Enter Payroll of an employee "
   echo
   echo -en "Enter employee name: "
   read Name

  #Retrieve current entry into individual fields                                                        
  line=`grep -i "$Name" $PAYROLL`
  Name=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
  EmployeeID=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
  EmployeeHP=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f3`
  EmployeeType=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f4` 

  #Check if entry exist in records
   if [ `count_lines "^${Name},"` -eq 0 ]
   then
       echo "Error: This particular record does not exist!!"
   else
      echo "$Name is ${EmployeeType} employee."


   if [ "$EmployeeType"="Salaried" ]
   then
    echo $EmployeeType  
    echo -en "Enter Weekly Salary :"
    read wsalary
    echo

   elif ["$EmployeeType"="Hourly" ]
   then
    echo -en "Enter hourly wage:"
    read hsalary
    echo -en "Enter hours worked this week:"
    read hours
    let "hwages = hsalary * hours"
    echo -en "Gross wages: \$$hwages"
    echo 

   elif ["$EmployeeType"="Commission" ]
   then
    echo -en "Enter Weekly Total Sales:"
    read csales
    echo -en "Gross wages:"
    read cwages
    echo 

   fi
   fi
   echo -en "Hit [Enter] to return to main menu..."
   read 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is problem area:

```
if [ "$EmployeeType"="Salaried" ]
```

You need spaces here around `=` operator:

```
if [ "$EmployeeType" = "Salaried" ]
```

and here:

```
elif [ "$EmployeeType" = "Hourly" ]
```

and here:

```
elif [ "$EmployeeType" = "Commission" ]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks but hit below error: 
./Assignment2.sh: line 187: [Commission: command not found
./Assignment2.sh: line 197: [Commission: command not found

Comment: Apply all the suggestions into your script and then test it. If doesn't work then post your updated script in your question.

Comment: Hi.. sorry it works now. :) Thank you so much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: That's perfect, please consider accepting this question whenever SO permits you to do so.